# Combining logistic regression and decision tree?

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, cart, ensemble-learning

I'm working on a project classifying patients as having (1) or not having (0) a particular condition. Someone I work with has suggested fitting a decision tree on this data, and using the leaf node membership as input to a logistic regression model. In other words, which leaf node a sample falls into is used to create a categorical variable for logistic regression. For a tree of depth 3, that would be 8 possible "classes". Is this a legitimate approach? The only thing I could find resembling this is [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/combining-logistic-regression-and-decision-tree-1adec36a4b3f).

This suggestion doesn't seem right to me, but wondering if anyone has encountered this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against this.

First off, if your model were to be used in the future, you would really need two models since the decision tree is used as an input to the logistic regression.

Second, decision trees are highly variable, so there is no guarantee that a patient would fall into the same leaf were you to add more data, or were they to be part of a different dataset.  Decision trees are highly unstable, which is why we typically use techniques like bagging to reduce their variance.

Third, if one of the leafs has all 1s or 0s, then the standard error for the coefficient for that leaf is going to be absurdly high.  See the example below

```r
library(tidyverse)
N<- 1000
leafs <- factor(sample(1:8, size = N, replace=T))
y <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
y[leafs==5] <- 0

tibble(leafs,y) %>% 
  group_by(leafs) %>% 
  summarise(
    y = sum(y),
    n = n()
  )

fit <- glm(y~leafs, family = binomial()) 
summary(fit)
```

If you're not doing inference, then this isn't a problem.  But if you are doing prediction, then there is some literature you should be abiding by, like TRIPOD which instead recommends you use splines to add non-linearity to the logistic regression.

All in all I would recommend *against* this approach.  I don't think any potential benefits are worth the very real thread of these points I've made.

Answer (score 0):

it is essentially a alternative way of binning . I don't see anything wrong with it mathematically. you also want to make sure your leaves are not too small, and the maybe do some bagging to check your final bins are stable.